# GridView not populating on Page_Load but on PostBack or Refresh

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, url-parameters

In an ASP.NET WebForms application there are just two controls in an aspx page, a DropDownList and a GridView. There is no default selected value of DropDownList on Page_Load. Changing the selection in DropDownList populates GridView accurately.

When the page is requested with a URL parameter such as `.../View_Details.aspx?C_ID=123`, the selected value in DropDownList changes but **GridView does not populate for the first time but refreshing the page shows the records for given URL parameter**.

ASPX markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="Data" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/HomePage.Master" CodeBehind="View_Details.aspx.vb" Inherits="App1.View_Details" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyCP" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="CIDCombo" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDSCID" DataTextField="CName" DataValueField="CID" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSCID" runat="server" ... ></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fld1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fld2" />
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
Private C_ID As Long
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.Connect...)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
Dim stSqlQry As String = ""

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    C_ID = CLng(Request.QueryString("C_ID"))
    If IsPostBack Then

    Else
        If C_ID > 0 Then
            CIDCombo.SelectedValue = C_ID.ToString
            LoadGVData(C_ID)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CIDCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CIDCombo.SelectedIndexChanged
    If CIDCombo.SelectedIndex >= 0 AndAlso CLng(CIDCombo.SelectedValue) > 0 Then
        LoadGVData(CLng(CIDCombo.SelectedValue))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoadGVData(ByVal lnCID As Long)
    Try
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
        stSqlQry = "SELECT Fld1, Fld2 ... WHERE CID = @CID"
        da = New SqlDataAdapter()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(stSqlQry, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", lnCID)
        Dim dtDataTableInc As DataTable = New DataTable("t_Data")
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dtDataTableInc)
        'SOME DATA MANIPULATION WITH DATATABLE'

        '****************************************************************************'
        'DEBUG MODE SHOWS DataTable HAS ROWS BUT DON'T SHOW UP FIRST TIME IN GRIDVIEW'
        '****************************************************************************'
        gvData.DataSource = dtDataTableInc
        gvData.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'EXCEPTION HANDLING
    Finally
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you say that you use UpdatePanels: if you don't use any of them, does the grid populate correctly?

Comment: I'll let me test that, but lets say that UpdatePanels have to be used then in that case what could be the solution?

Comment: Another hypothesis: could the Load event come too early for binding your grid data? Could you try in the PreRender (or LoadComplete) event instead?

Comment: No, with UpdatePanel, without UpdatePanel, in PreRender, LoadComplete, it works neither way.

Comment: Hmmm, that is an "interesting" case...

Comment: The opposite hypothesis would be that these events come too late. In that case, I guess you would have to try in the "Init" event. I don't know why that would work but, since I don't see why your current code doesn't work anyway...

Comment: Sorry if you've tried this, but have you tried using Visual Studio to step through the logic line by line and inspected the variables at each step?  That way you can determine that the page truly is calling your LoadGVData method when it's not a postback and there is a c_id (and also that it's setting the selected value correctly).  I seem to recall having issues in some scenarios setting the selected value and instead had to go through the list items and select my value that way (worth a shot, would be quick to try out).

Comment: @b.pell He said in a reply to another answer that the DataTable has the records.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I meant that it was correctly pulling in the C_ID (and that C_ID is correct and not pulling in extra something from the query string like an encoded space, etc.) and passing it along to the load function (and that something subsequently might not be happening that wipes it out, something that would be obvious by having the debugger step through line by line).

Comment: @b.pell Forget about C_ID. If DataTable has rows and we assign it to the GridView the records should show up

Comment: @b.pell If the DataTable has records just before binding the GridView to it, at least these data should show up in the grid. Maybe he could monitor the DataBound event of the grid, to check that the data-binding went well (checking that the GridView has rows).

Comment: @b.pell If data binding would have been the issue then same code should also not have run on `SelectedIndexChanged` event

Comment: I assume that you see nothing of the grid, not even headers, it that right? If you force headers to show up, do you see them? (ShowHeader=true, ShowHeaderWhenEmpty=true)

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `AutoEventWireup="false"` put it on true.

**Just a general note:**

When working with DropDownLists and using `AutoPostBack=True`
make use of an `UpdatePanel` since the User gets frustrated when he always see a white page flickering :)

if you use an `UpdatePanel` you use the `Onload` event to populate your data
and put `UpdateMode=Conditional`

Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: While the page is loading for the first time (IsPostBack will always be false), DataTable has the records and then assigning it to the grid along with DataBind should have displayed the records. And as regards to UpdatePanel these are already used. I have posted only the relevant code. **PostBack/refresh is NOT an issue. I 've already mentioned issue is first load**

Comment: Okey lemme think further

Comment: Happend me allot of time as well when creating a new WebForm in .vb :P
very frustrating :P

Comment: setting AutoEventWireup to true/false, no effect